# How to draw texture at mouse coords using keyboard

Tags: c++, sdl

Its like the title suggests, i want to draw a "1" texture at mouse coords using a keyboard key press.
I am using switch statements for input:

```
switch (e.type)
                {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                {
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                {
                    switch (e.button.button)
                    {
  
                    case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:
                    {
                        SDL_Rect rect = {e.motion.x - 10, e.motion.y - 10, 20, 20};
                        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gT[0], NULL, &rect);
                        printf("nod\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                {
                    switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                    case SDLK_c:
                    {
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
                        printf("tot ecranul\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    case SDLK_1:
                    {
                        SDL_Rect rect = {e.motion.x - 8, e.motion.y - 8, 16, 16};
                        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gT[3], NULL, &rect);
                        printf("1\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
```

I tried some random things, and no success so far.

`gT[3]` is the "1" texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.motion` only makes sense when `e` is a mouse event.

Call [`SDL_GetMouseState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState) to get the current mouse position.

Comment: Can u write the code using the one i provided above?  I cant figure it out how to make it work.

Comment: Did you look at the example code in the linked page? It's really not that complicated.

Comment: Yea, i wote this `case SDLK_1:
                    {
                        buttons = SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);

                        SDL_Rect rect = {buttons - 8, buttons - 8, 16, 16};
                        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gT[3], NULL, &rect);
                        printf("1\n");
                        break;
                    }` and it still doesn t work

Comment: You need to read a book on basic C++. `x` and `y` must be defined somewhere. `buttons` isn't the mouse position, I think that's clear from the name and from the "Return Value" section in the wiki page.

Comment: I defined them, just not showed them here, but i cant wrap my head around that function, thats all. I simply cant understand it, maybe i am too new, but thats why i need the help

Comment: Maybe you need to take a break from your code, because this seems extremely obvious to me. `x` and `y` are the mouse position, you need to pass their address to `SDL_GetMouseState` so that it can modify their value. Then you just use `x` and `y` in your `rect` instead of `buttons`. You don't need `buttons` anywhere in your code, discard it.

Comment: Definetely i need it, ive been here for 4 hours, now it makes sense, im just tired, anyway thx for the help and patience, good night!